# GCP Data Fusion multiple table import

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm trying to use Multiple Database Tables and BigQuery Multi Table Data Fusion plugin to import multiple table in one pipeline

[image: Pipeline]

But when I try to execute I get the following error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BigQuery Multi Table has no outputs. Please check that the sink calls addOutput at some point.
```

I'm using Data Fusion version 6.1.4 Multiple Database Tables version 1.2.0 and BigQuery Multi Table version 0.14.8.

Any suggestion on what may be the problem?

Edit:

following the configuration of multiple table database source

```
{
            "name": "Multiple Database Tables",
            "plugin": {
                "name": "MultiTableDatabase",
                "type": "batchsource",
                "label": "Multiple Database Tables",
                "artifact": {
                    "name": "multi-table-plugins",
                    "version": "1.2.0",
                    "scope": "USER"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "splitsPerTable": "1",
                    "referenceName": "multiTable",
                    "connectionString": "${secure(connection)}",
                    "jdbcPluginName": "netezza",
                    "user": "${secure(username)}",
                    "password": "${secure(password)}",
                    "whiteList": "categoria_l,cliente_l,regione_l"
                }
            },
            "outputSchema": [
                {
                    "name": "etlSchemaBody",
                    "schema": ""
                }
            ]
        },
```

After further test the problem is that the source response is empty because data fusion is not reading view from source database but only tables

Comment: Did your pipeline finish successfully, populating the tables to Bigquery sink?

Comment: It seems that `BigQuery Multi Table` plugin doesn't produce any Output schema but basically spreads Bigquery Job to insert/update columns across the tables.

Comment: The data previously is stored in temporary GCS bucket, and then imported to Bigquery tables.

Comment: @Nick_Kh no if i run the pipeline fails with the error reported in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `Multiple Database Tables` **source** produced no records ("Out 0"). I'd check there first. You can do a quick check using the Preview mode. Plugin doc [here](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/718831924/Multiple+Database+Tables+Batch+Source).

Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64393046/47551).

Comment: The source tables are not empty because I have a pipeline for each table that imports data correctly. Since each table has few rows I tried to use multiple table to reduce import time.

Comment: I added the configuration of Multiple Database Tables source. I think the problem may be that I haven't set Table Name Pattern but where i can find the syntax for pattern?

Comment: After further testing the problem was the plug in empty response of multiple table source because seems reading only tables and not views.

Comment: I changed the plugin to also allow Views - here's the diff: 
https://github.com/data-integrations/multi-table-plugins/compare/develop...carlosmarin:source-views
and here's the artifact: 
https://github.com/carlosmarin/multi-table-views-plugins-1.3.5 
To use it you'll have to upload the JAR using the big green plus sign in Data Studio.