# Google Cloud Data Fusion, How can I load many tables to bigquery in one pipeline

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I want to load many tables which is in aws rds mysql server by using cloud data fusion. each table storage is more than about 1gb. also I found the plugin which name is "multiple database table" to load multi table. but i got a fail. Also basically when I used database source I can check my tables' schema. However, in multiple database table, i can 't find how to check table's schema. how can i use this plugin? or is there any other way to load many tables in data fusion service?

My pipeline setting was as follows.
[image]

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? If I understand correctly, you want to load your AWS RDS tables to GCP BigQuery. What error did you get? Do you have any network restrictions? Do you allow a GCP <> AWS connection (are you using VPN)? Could you provide the exact steps you have followed?

Comment: `@PjoterS`
thank you for your comment. exactly  I want to migrate many tables in my RDS mysql to GCP storage or bigquery. I found a way to migrate one table in one pipeline, but I don't know how to migrate multiple tables in one pipeline.  However, I understand that multiple database table  is used to implement this. However, I don't know how to use it.

in summary, I want to know how to use multiple database table source to migrate many tables to google cloud storage or bigquery

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64368503/gcp-data-fusion-multiple-table-import?rq=1) is the same problem I'm having.

Comment: I was wondering if you exactly need to use a pipeline or you just need to migrate your DB from AWS to GCP. For example [here](https://hevodata.com/learn/rds-to-bigquery/) you have example how to do it using `.CSV` However if you need pipeline, did you see `Muhammad Izzuddin` tutorial: Building a Simple Batch Data Pipeline from AWS RDS to Google BigQuery — [Part 1: Setting UP AWS Data pipeline](https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/building-a-simple-batch-data-pipeline-from-aws-rds-to-google-bigquery-part-1-setting-up-aws-b7787ffb6805)

Comment: and [Part 2: Setting up BigQuery Transfer Service and Scheduled Query](https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/building-a-simple-batch-data-pipeline-from-aws-rds-to-google-bigquery-part-2-setting-up-6d2bbca75448). From what I understand this should solve your issue. If not, could you please elaborate what exactly scenario you have?

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this `Community Wiki` as OP didn't provide enough details to reproduce but the below information might help someone.

There are few ways to get your data using [Cloud Data Fusion](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion), you can use `pipeline`, `plugin`, `driver` and a few others depending on your needs.

On the internet you can find two very well described guides with examples.

If you would like to find some information about `Cloud Data Fusion` with GCP products you should read `Bahadir Bulut` guide - [How I used Google Cloud Data Fusion to create a data warehouse - Part 1](https://gcloud.devoteam.com/blog/how-i-used-google-cloud-data-fusion-to-create-a-data-warehouse-part-1) and [Part 2](https://gcloud.devoteam.com/blog/how-i-used-google-cloud-data-fusion-to-create-a-data-warehouse-part-2). Also `Data Fusion` allows to use **150+** preconfigured [connectors and transformations](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/plugins) like Amazons S3, SQS, etc. Azure services and many more.

Another well described (which I guess would help OP) is to configure both `Amazon` and `GCP` resources and using `pipelines`. This guide is [Building a Simple Batch Data Pipeline from AWS RDS to Google BigQuery — Part 1: Setting UP AWS Data pipeline](https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/building-a-simple-batch-data-pipeline-from-aws-rds-to-google-bigquery-part-1-setting-up-aws-b7787ffb6805) and second part [Building a Simple Batch Data Pipeline from AWS RDS to Google BigQuery — Part 2: Setting up BigQuery Transfer Service and Scheduled Query.](https://medium.com/thelorry-product-tech-data/building-a-simple-batch-data-pipeline-from-aws-rds-to-google-bigquery-part-2-setting-up-6d2bbca75448). In short this guide describes 2 main steps:

1. Extract data from `MYSQL RDS` and bring into `S3` using `AWS data pipeline` service
2. From `S3`, bring the file inside `Bigquery` using `BigqQuery transfer service`.